# Is it bad to skip exception constructor overloads if you're not going to use them?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

According to MSDN's [Best Practices for Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you should create three constructors for your custom exceptions, namely `Exception()`, `Exception(String)`, and `Exception(String, Exception)`:

> In C# and C++, use at least the three common constructors when creating your own exception classes: the default constructor, a constructor that takes a string message, and a constructor that takes a string message and an inner exception. For an example, see [How to: Create User-Defined Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx).

Such a blanket statement strikes me as a bit odd considering that you can use an exception purely internally in your software, in one specific way, and never intend for it to be caught or thrown by external code.

For example, I'm creating software for converting between two file formats. Before conversion, I check the input file for non-unique IDs (it shouldn't have and usually doesn't - this is exceptional behaviour), and if found, raise my own `DuplicateIdException`:

```
public class DuplicateIdException : Exception
{

    public DuplicateIdException(List<string> ids)
    {
        Duplicates = ids;
    }

    public List<string> Duplicates { get; }
}
```

This exception is caught further up the stack, the duplicate IDs logged, and the conversion process aborted. Since this is the only usage scenario for this exception, I will only ever use that one constructor. I don't even need the ubiquitous `message` parameter for anything (though if I did, I'd just add it to this constructor.)

I just don't see the reason to have unused code that allows unintended uses by future maintainers (including myself, having forgot all about this a year down the road).

In cases such as these, is it bad practice to omit the other constructors? If so, why? Are there any pitfalls to be aware of?

Comment: "best practices" aren't hard and fast rules: you have to use your own judgement about when to apply them.

Comment: @stuartd Sure, just wanting to know if there are any pitfalls I'm not aware of. Specified that in the question now.

Comment: What about an exception that is part of an API? So the exception-cause is very wide-spread? How will you ever determine that this will allways be the only usage of this exception then?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Not sure what you mean. I'm explicitly talking about an exception where I control all throws and and catches.

Comment: Then it´s OK, I guess. As stuard allready mentions "conventions" and "best practices" exist for the purpose of communication towards others. You *can* follow them, however feel free to ignore them when you consider them irrelevant in your scenario.